# How to create device file symlink

Tags: catalina, symlink

ok - bit convoluted, but I'm creating a tool that emulates a GPS device. Combination of C code and a tool called SOCAT. SOCAT reads a udp port and passes the data to my C Code which decodes the data and pumps out a GPS sentence.

The GPS sentence is then (theoretically) passed back to SOCAT which creates virtual PTY device which can then be accessed to provide positioning information.

Unfortunately, SOCAT is only creating the following device /dev/ttys002 which is lovely, but not quite where I want it. SOCAT has an option to 'link' to another device name, which will ideally be /dev/cu.serial02 or something like that.

Catalina is actively preventing me from putting in a symlink - even as sudo/root.

Any idea how I can get around this /dev limitation ?

Comment: Why does the device name matter at all?

Comment: The target software requires it, or so I thought. There may be a further constraint. I am targeting Google Earth Pro, which will scan an enumeration of serial devices for one supplying NMEA sentences. I managed to disable CSR and get this done, however creating a serial device in this way with a symlink didn't have the desired effect. GEPro still won't scan my new serial port.

Comment: A device name is just a name for a device node with some characteristics/attributes. Maybe some things are missing which Google Earth requires to recognize it as a serial device.

Comment: I've got a similar question, for a similar reason. No software I've found lists `socat` created ports while scanning for serial ports (although they seem to be able to open them when directly given the `/dev/ttysXXX` name). I'm intrigued by @nohillside's comment, but don't really know how to move forward with it.